# How to test file upload in vue3 using jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, quasar-framework

I want to use jest to write unit test for upload file and export excel
but when I write upload file,I met this exception:
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
Expected: {} Received: undefined

How to solve this exception?

```
here is my code

`<template>
  <div class="q-gutter-y-xs row items-start">
    <q-card flat style="width: 100%" dense>      
      <Page-Content
        ref="pageContent"
      >
        <template #header>
          <div class="q-px-md">
            <div class="q-gutter-sm row">
              <q-item class="col-4 col-sm-12" style="margin-left: 0">                
                <q-file
                  name="selectuploadfile"
                  standout="bg-blue-1 text-indigo"
                  outlined
                  dense
                  style="width: 270px"
                  v-model="ExcelList"
                  :label="$t('select_upload_file')"
                >
                  <template v-slot:prepend>
                    <q-icon name="cloud_upload" @click.stop />
                  </template>
                  <template v-slot:append>
                    <q-icon
                      name="close"
                      @click.stop="ExcelList = null"
                      class="cursor-pointer"
                    />
                  </template>
                </q-file>
                <q-btn
                  :label="$t('upload')"
                  @click="importExcel"
                />
                <q-btn    
                  :label="$t('upload_sample')"
                  href="./UploadSample/AverageYearsDataDefine.xlsx"
                />
                <q-btn
                  :label="$t('export_to_excel')"
                  @click="exportExcel"
                />
              </q-item>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </Page-Content>
    </q-card>
  </div>
</template>`
```

here is test code :

```
describe('AverageYearsDataDefine', () => {
  it('fill up form', async () => {    

    const file = new File(['test file'], 'test.xlsx', {
      type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    });
    const fileInput = wrapper.get('[name="selectuploadfile"]');
    await fileInput.trigger('change', file);
    expect(wrapper.vm.ExcelList).toEqual(file);
  });
});
```

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
Expected: {} Received: undefined